# Jxls : How to define template programmatically and use in transformer?

Tags: java, excel, templates, transformer-model, jxls

I am using Jxls to output data to excel. The no. of columns is not fixed and depends on who is calling it. So how to define template programatically?

In Jxls documentation, there are three ways of doing it, using excel markup, xml mark up and Java Apis. Using Java Apis, XmlArea is defined but one of the constructor takes transformer as a parameter

```
public XlsArea(AreaRef areaRef, Transformer transformer);

 public XlsArea(String areaRef, Transformer transformer);

 public XlsArea(CellRef startCell, CellRef endCell, Transformer transformer);

 public XlsArea(CellRef startCellRef, Size size, List<CommandData> commandDataList, Transformer transformer);
```

`Transformer constructor` requires a `inputstream`, which requires a `template` file.

```
InputStream in = IdGenre.class.getResourceAsStream("/xlsTemplates/IdGenre/IdGenreTemplate.xlsx");

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(in, out);
```

From what I understand, `template` is where it is defined what value goes in columns.

Using `SimpleExporter`:

```
try(OutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream("target/simple_export_output1.xls")) {
        List<Employee> employees = generateSampleEmployeeData();
        List<String> headers = Arrays.asList("Name", "Birthday", "Payment");
        SimpleExporter exporter = new SimpleExporter();
        exporter.gridExport(headers, employees, "name, birthDate, payment", os1);
```

`It requires a transformer and throws exception.`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.List org.jxls.transform.Transformer.getCommentedCells()' on a null object reference
```

How can I create a template programmatically or how can work with `SimpleExporter`? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.